# Evaluating integrals with a function in the limit of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been looking at this problem for a while and can seem to find how to solve it.

I think I have to use the fundamental theory of calculus to solve it but do not know how.

Find the derivative of
$$F(x)=\int^{0}_{x^2-1}\frac{\sin(t+1)}{t+1}dt.$$

Comment: Look at "differentiating under the integral".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that, if
$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt,$$
then $F'(x)=f(x)$.  Together with the chain rule, that gives you
$$\frac{d}{dx}F(g(x)) = F'(g(x))g'(x).$$
Now, this is directly applicable to your $F$, which can be written

$$F(x)=-\int_0^{x^2-1}\frac{\sin(t+1)}{t+1}dt.$$

Comment: Thanks the negative is exactly what i was missing